# Difference between ACTION_WEB_SEARCH and EXTRA_WEB_SEARCH_ONLY

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm implementing speech recognition in my app and have some questions the API doc couldn't solve. I wonder what's the difference between using

```
Intent recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
```

and

```
Intent recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
```

?

I also recognized that I have to put the `EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL` also when using `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`? Why is that?

And what means `EXTRA_WEB_SEARCH_ONLY`? I thought that it is always web search with the web search action.